# Parsing yaml file using yaml-cpp new API - Issue Fixed

Tags: c++, yaml-cpp

I am using yaml-cpp 0.6 latest to parse an yaml file.

my yaml file looks like this,

```
-person: p1
 obj: 
   name: x
   age: 27
-person: p2
 obj:
   name: y
   age:38
```

my code,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <yaml-cpp/yaml.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    YAML::Node config = YAML::LoadFile("config.yaml");
    if(config.IsNull())
    {
        cout << "return";
    }

    cout << "size: " << config.size() << endl;
    for(YAML::iterator it = config.begin(); it != config.end(); ++it)
    {
        YAML::Node node = *it;
        cout << "node size: " << node.size() << endl;
        //for(YAML::iterator it2 = node.begin(); it2!=node.end(); ++it2) {}
        //iterating over node throws seg fault
        cout << node << endl;
        cout << "-----" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The o/p I see is,

```
return
size: 2
node size: 2
node size: 2

obj:
  name: x
  age: 27
person: p1
2
-----
person: p2
obj:
  age: 38
  name: y
```

Please help me understand why the root node, config is Null in my case though its size returns 2.
Also if config though Null is iterable, why not node then?
Iterating over node throws seg fault and so commented.
How to iterate over node to list persons in my case and read each person's attribute?
How to get name, age.. using something like node["person"]["name"] ?

Its a mistake from my side. Not sure, if it is because of the wrong installation of libyaml-cpp... It started working once, removed and reinstalled the libyaml-cpp0.5/libyaml-cpp-dev.
Thanks!

Comment: I seem to have run into the same problem of the top-level node being null when I upgraded to version 0.6. Did you ever go back to 0.6 and get it figured out?

Answer (score 0):

first thing to note here is: Yaml is very sensitive to formatting, eg. spaces. Can you first try to parse your Yaml with some online yaml parser.

I've just tried it using the [yaml-online-parser](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/), please see the following doc (eg. two spaces indentation, always a space between key/value)

```
- person: p1
  obj: 
    name: x
    age: 27

- person: p2
  obj:
    name: y
    age: 38
```

Your providing a list of two `person` objects, i guess that's why your root-nodes `config.IsNull()` returns true.

Can you try to check the objects type, eg. like in the [yaml-cpp tutorial](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/wiki/Tutorial):

```
switch (node.Type()) {
  case Null: // ...
  case Scalar: // ...
  case Sequence: // ...
  case Map: // ...
  case Undefined: // ...
}
```

I haven't tested the following, but it may work within your for loop:

```
string name(""), age("");
if (node["obj"] == NULL) continue;

if (node["obj"]["name"]) {
     name = node["obj"]["name"].as<std::string>();
}

if (node["obj"]["age"]) {
    age = node["obj"]["age"].as<std::string>();
}
```